# Any possible reason why Masonry works only on localhost?

Tags: javascript, meteor, jquery-masonry, masonry

I use Masonry for Meteor - https://github.com/sjorssnoeren/meteor-masonry/. Everything works alright on localhost, but once I deploy the application, it doesn't work like it does on localhost. What is the reason and how do I make it work please ?

Comment: It's a little hard to say without knowing how your project is set up. Are there any errors in your browser console? When you say it doesn't work, what's wrong? Does masonry work partially, or not at all?

Comment: it works now magically, but I have no idea what was wrong actually

Comment: The problem was, that I set rendering on 200 milliseconds, what was too early and it couldn't get it rendered live.